# Explanation of unexpected nesting with @extend in SASS

Tags: sass

I have a nested class `.super &` and I cannot figure out why the `.one_two--alt` class is being prefixed by the `.super` class even though the markup suggests it shouldn't.

**SCSS**

```
.one{
  &__two{
    color: red;
    &--alt{
      @extend .one__two;
    }
    .super &{
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

**Outputed CSS:**

```
.one__two, .one__two--alt {
  color: red;
}
.super .one__two, .super .one__two--alt {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Expected CSS**

```
.one__two, .one__two--alt {
  color: red;
}
.super .one__two{
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by extending with class (and not with placeholder) you change the value of `&`, to be more precise you add more selectors to it, hence you have additional `--alt` class bound to `&` and later prefixed with `.super` (by you).

By using sass placeholders you can get correct output.

```
%red{ color: red }

.one {
  &__two{
    @extend %red;
    &--alt { @extend %red}
    .super & { color: blue }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh... Cheers. I'll use placeholders instead.