# Sass: Extending nested selectors

Tags: css, sass

(I think I should mention this, I've only recently started using Sass/SCSS)

http://jsfiddle.net/DriftingSteps/t6kLncfm/

You can see how `<strong>` is inheriting the properties of the global `<a>` as well as the properties from nested `<a>` tag.

```
a {
    color: #09f;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
}

ul {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    a {
        font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #0a3;
    }
    strong {
        @extend a;
    }
}
```

I have been going through http://sass-lang.com/ and I know I'm missing something.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to inherit properties from the nested `<a>` only, without the use of classes on either `ul a` and `ul strong`? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204325/explanation-of-unexpected-nesting-with-extend-in-sass/30215791#30215791) on similair question couple of days ago, it should be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [extend-only selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders) (`%`), and extend both `ul a` and `ul strong` from that:

```
a {
    color: #09f;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
}

ul {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    a {
      @extend %a;
    }
    strong {
        @extend %a;
    }
}

%a {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #0a3;
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use the extend-only selector here, even if I'm unsure OP really needs @extend.

Comment: Yes, I see why @extend isn't necessary in this particular condition, but I believe I should be using the extend-only selector. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to *use* that class and you don't have to apply it to your HTML, you can just define it and refer to it when inheriting:

```
a, .a {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #0a3;
}
strong {
    @extend .a;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/z1cuo68x/)

And of course, in this case you don't really need extend:

```
a, strong {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #0a3;
}
strong {
    // other stuff
}
```

It seems to me that the real use case of extend isn't deep localized selectors defined together, but rather the extension of a selector defined elsewhere.

Comment: I see why extend isn't a better option in this case, but what about cases in which `a` and `strong` have conflicting properties (like different background colors)? Use the extend-only selector? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DriftingSteps In that case you can just define three rules: one of `a`, one for `strong`, and one with the common properties. In the case of local selectors, I find this clearer than using @extend which means you declare then override.